# Azure ARM template deployment using Python

Tags: python, azure-resource-manager

I am looking for ARM deployment for Storage Account using Python. That is, I am looking for a Python equivalent of powershell's **new-azresourcegroupdeployment** cmdlet.

I have been looking at some links, but I am not able to find any.

[This link,](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-template-deployment) has some 'deployer' class, but it is very specific to linux VM. And I think there should be a very easy way to do it. I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example will work with any template with a little modification. Specifically, the Deployment.deploy() method is where you want to look for an example of resource group deployment with a template.

The main thing you would need to change is the properties. The ones in the example are specific to the Linux VM template, so you would need to change those to the ones in your
Storage template or remove them if you are not using parameters in your template at all.

```
def deploy(self):
    """Deploy the template to a resource group."""
    self.client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
        self.resource_group,
        {
            'location': 'westus'
        }
    )

    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
        __file__), 'templates', 'template.json')
    with open(template_path, 'r') as template_file_fd:
        template = json.load(template_file_fd)

    parameters = {                    #<------- Update this with your template's parameters
        'sshKeyData': self.pub_ssh_key,
        'vmName': 'azure-deployment-sample-vm',
        'dnsLabelPrefix': self.dns_label_prefix
    }
    parameters = {k: {'value': v} for k, v in parameters.items()}

    deployment_properties = {
        'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
        'template': template,
        'parameters': parameters
    }

    deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.create_or_update(
        self.resource_group,
        'azure-sample',
        deployment_properties
    )
    deployment_async_operation.wait()
```